# How to get the facebook comment using HttParty

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, httparty

When i am trying to fetch the comments the i am getting this error message.

```
article_url = "http://de.richarddawkins.net/articles/atheist-stephen-hawking-negiert-existenz-eines-gottes-die-wissenschaft-biete-eine-uberzeugendere-erklarung-des-universums"

HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=#{article_url}")

#<HTTParty::Response:0xb4fa49c parsed_response={"error"=>{"message"=>"An access token is required to request this resource.", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>104, "fbtrace_id"=>"Asfda7D+/qM"}}, @response=#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>, @headers={"www-authenticate"=>["OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_token\" \"An access token is required to request this resource.\""], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "cache-control"=>["no-store"], "facebook-api-version"=>["v2.2"], "expires"=>["Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"], "content-type"=>["application/json; charset=UTF-8"], "x-fb-trace-id"=>["Asfda7D+/qM"], "x-fb-rev"=>["2778708"], "vary"=>["Accept-Encoding"], "x-fb-debug"=>["pSZo8HXiIaM0tu9f0ss+swqnhShjgCQYpm3GN8GQS+olRNjmwTfiHPPE/8xZJRxu787j7JlwCHW9kwuayjcgeA=="], "date"=>["Mon, 16 Jan 2017 06:23:43 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"], "content-length"=>["139"]}>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to just add ACCESS_TOKEN into your query string.

Ex.

```
HTTParty.get("https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=#{article_url}&access_token=#{ACCESS_TOKEN}")
```

Hope it's work

Comment: How do i get the access token.?

Comment: Now i am getting this response.

"error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (URL)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "EWtQwBilDfZ"
   }

Comment: ok..now this is permission issue, you need to check do you have permission to get comments.